# LINQ Expression to combine / join

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, join

I'm working on a recipe manager program, using Entity Framework 6 code first.  I have the following entities in the database:

```
public class Item {
    [DatabaseGenerated( DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity ), Key]        
    public int ItemId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ItemName {get; set; }

    // Other properties
}

public class Recipe {
    [DatabaseGenerated( DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity ), Key]
    public int RecipeId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string RecipeName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; }

    // Other properties
}

public class Ingredient {
    [Key, Column( Order = 0 )]
    public int RecipeId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey( "RecipeId" )]
    public virtual Recipe Recipe { get; set; }

    [Key, Column( Order = 1 )]
    public int ItemId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey( "ItemId" )]
    public virtual Item Item { get; set; }

    public double Quantity { get; set; }

    // Other properties
}

public class Meal {
    [DatabaseGenerated( DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity ), Key]        
    public int MealId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string MealName {get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Recipe> Recipes { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<Ingredient> Ingredients() {
        if ( Recipes == null )
            yield break;

        foreach ( var recipe in Recipes )
            foreach ( var ingredient in recipe.Ingredients )
                yield return ingredient;
    }
}
```

My problem is the `Ingredients` property in the `Meal` class.  The code there will return a list of all ingredients needed to make the meal, but I want to return a combined list. That is, if one recipe in the meal needs 2 eggs and another one needs 1 egg, this returns two entries for eggs. I want to return one entry for 3 eggs.

Is there a LINQ expression I can use to combine these?  Something equivalent to:

```
SELECT item.ItemName, SUM(ing.Quantity)
FROM Meals AS m
JOIN RecipeMeals AS rm ON m.MealId = rm.Meal_MealId
JOIN Ingredients AS ing ON rm.Recipe_RecipeId = ing.RecipeId
JOIN Items AS item ON ing.ItemId = item.ItemId
GROUP BY item.ItemName
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have **navigation properties** defined (and you do have them), it's quite easy - no need to think for joins, just "navigate" as if they are objects. EF will produce the necessary SQL joins for you.

The equivalent LINQ to Entities query is like this:

```
from meal in db.Meals
from recipe in meal.Recipes
from ingredient in recipe.Ingredients
let item = ingredient.Item
group ingredient by item.ItemName into itemGroup
select new { ItemName = itemGroup.Key, Quantity = itemGroup.Sum(e => e.Quantity) }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var result = from m in Meals
    join rm in RecipeMeals on m.MealId equals rm.Meal_MealId
    join ing in Ingredients on rm.Recipe_RecipeId equals ing.RecipeId
    join item in Items on ing.ItemId equals item.ItemId
    group ing by item.ItemName into g
    select new { g.Key, g.Sum(p => p.Quantity) }
```

Comment: This doesn't work. The entity model does not have an entity for the `RecipeMeals` table.

Comment: What do you mean by, 'The entity model does not have an entity for the RecipeMeals table.'? Couldn't you add it? What I posted here is an exact translation of your SQL query to Linq.

Comment: I'm using Entity Framework code first. I created the classes in the first listing, then added a class descending from `DbContext` to build the entity model. There just aren't any classes in the model for the many-to-many relation tables. Instead, there are navigation properties.